# After attempt to repair python3.10.6 dependency issues in Lubuntu 20.04.1 graphical environment starts no longer automatically during boot

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Fresh installed Lububtu 22.10 first boot message is "Out of memory".
Installed a second time with the same result.

Comment: Is it Lubuntu 20.04.1 or 22.10 - please double check version.

Comment: The title and the body of the message have noting to do with each other.

Comment: That is true. I have continued the investigation and in the body, you find the new status and the initial status removed. I am not able to change the title afterwards.

Comment: Space is insufficient for the answer and format is not accepted for comment. Which person did invent these rules?

Comment: lubuntu@lubuntu:\~\$ sudo more /var/log/boot.log

------------ Wed Oct 26 17:48:30 UTC 2022 ------------

useradd warning: lubuntu's uid 999 outside of the UID\_MIN 1000 and
UID\_MAX 60000 range.